# execute query (table creation) present in Access 97 database from vb.net fails

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When executing a query (that generates a new table) present in an Access 97 database from a separate VB.net program, the table gets created but it ends up with 0 records. If I execute the same query directly in the Access 97 database, the records are created.

This is the code I am using and which executes fine without any errors:

```
Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    Dim sConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Password=xx;User ID=username;" & _
      "Data Source=\\FILESERVER\TestMyAgents.mdb;" & _
      "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
      "Jet OLEDB:System database=\\FILESERVER\backend\mdw\system.mdw"
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    conn = New OleDbConnection(sConStr)

    cmd1.Connection = conn
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd1.CommandText = "Query1"

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

Any ideas why the records are not created?

EDIT: this is the SQL-statement in the Query1:

```
    SELECT epo.description, epo.date, epo.voucher, epo.application_number, Sum(epo.amount) AS SommaDiamount INTO test33
FROM epo
GROUP BY epo.description, epo.date, epo.voucher, epo.application_number
HAVING (((epo.description) Like "*13017pt*"));
```

Comment: What is the SQL statement text from *Query1*?

Comment: added the sql statement in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using OleDb to connect to the Access db, you need different wild card characters in the `Like` pattern:

```sql
HAVING (((epo.description) Like "%13017pt%"));
```

With OleDb, the `*` character is not interpreted as a wild card.  Instead, the db engine treats it as just the literal `*` character.  And, since apparently none of the rows had `epo.description` equal to *"*13017pt*"*, the query returned no rows.

Comment: Many thanks. Worked fine. Honestly had no idea about the need to change the wildcard.

Comment: Now reading your explanation, everything is much clearer. Very good answer. Much appreciated.